How to "upgrade" from 18.04 to 24.04 while preserving firefox and thunderbird data
Ladies, gentlemen and those still undecided,
I'm moving from 18.04 to 24.04. How do I preserve the passwords bookmarks and other data in firefox and mozilla? When I moved from 16.04 to 18.04 I just copied the profiles over. I understand this no longer works. I'm not very familiar with what's under the hood here so please use small words and type slowly.
Thank you in advance.

This question is similar to: Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Following the normal release-upgrade path will ensure your profiles remain; however 18.04 will only upgrade to 20.04, from 20.04 you can upgrade to 22.04, and from 22.04 you can upgrade to 24.04, but that's multiple release-upgrades.  Just backup & follow the instructions (reading both upgrade instructions & release notes for each step!)

FYI:  I'm not sure what you mean by "copying profiles .. no longer working" as you give no specifics; but I've had no issues moving my profiles around (which includes from deb packaged firefox to the snap packaged firefox; and the reverse direction too.. however I've not tried from a release that is EOSS or EOL as you specify)   Though firefox and thunderbird are only snap supported on 18.04 since April 2023; so I assume you're starting with with snap packaged apps even though you don't specify.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/ESM/18.04

The simplest way (and the method I have used successfully over time moving from one version/distro to another) is to set up an account in Firefox then log in to the new instance. This will bring across all your Bookmarks. Use Ctrl+B to display the Bookmarks sidebar.
For Thunderbird, export your email setup/accounts in TB by clicking on the hamburger menu ☰ and select Tools -> Export (perhaps save to a USB stick for easy access) then in the new instance, follow the same path but use import and find the .zip file you save earlier. This will recreate the email accounts in the new instance.
I use imap for emails so the emails themselves are retained on the remote server.

If I understand you correctly you want to make a fresh install with 24.04 and then only transfer Thunderbird and Firefox profiles from your old Linux installation.
If so you can still transfer your Firefox and Thunderbird profiles. Only the places where the profiles are stored have changed because this programms are now installed using "Snaps" instead of "Deb-Files" .

Firefox changed from /home/yourname/.mozilla/firefox to /home/yourname/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox
Thunderbird changed from /home/yourname/.thunderbird to /home/yourname/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird

As always: Make sure you have a backup of your files!


On your old system:
Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + t).
Find your Thunderbird and Firefox data folders in your /home directory:
find ~/ -name "*.default" -type d

On my computer I got the following result:
/home/digijay/.mozilla/firefox/wE1rdCh4.default
/home/digijay/.thunderbird/0th4wRdc.default

Copy these files to a save location, e.g. a usb drive:
cp -r ~/.mozilla/firefox/wE1rdCh4.default ~/.thunderbird/0th4wRdc.default /media/digijay/myusbdrive/

Make sure that you don't get any errors to prevent data loss! At least check that both folders are on the usb key. In my case I used rsync to copy the folders which is a little saver than cp imo.
On your new system:
You will have to install (or have already installed) the snap images of Firefox and Thunderbird. To use your old data there insert your usb drive and copy the folders from your usb drive to the following locations:
cp -r /media/digijay/myusbdrive/.mozilla/firefox/wE1rdCh4.default ~/snap/firefox/common/
cp -r /media/digijay/myusbdrive/.thunderbird/0th4wRdc.default ~/snap/thunderbird/common/

Start both snap apps and check if everything is there as expected (browser history and bookmarks, old mails and addressbooks).
I migrated my data in this way a while back and it worked well. Should you happen to have more than one email adress configured in Thunderbird (as in my case) copy all profile folders to ~/snap/thunderbird/common/
